# replacing/overwriting standard-output in lisp

Tags: lisp, overwrite

i'm writing a chronometer in common lisp, output is being displayed in standard-output. what i'm trying to do is replace the output without printing a newline and without printing side-by-side but by overwriting the previous output so there is an illusion of continuity.

is there anyway to do this in common lisp?

Comment: what is standard output going to? A file? A network connection? A terminal? What kind of a terminal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, after reading the comments, I understand your intentions much better. From you original question, I assumed you wanted to replace/augment the output of some other code. But now I understand, what you actually want is to **update the screen**. This cannot be done with stream-based IO alone, you need some other kind of IO library like ncurses.

A Common Lisp binding for ncurses is the system cl-charms (available in QuickLisp). There is no cl-charms specific documentation, but the documentation for using ncurses in C can be applied almost unchanged. Here is a simple implementation for the task you're describing, ie. it displays (for 10 seconds) a clock in the left upper corner of the screen:

```
(defun clock ()
  (charms:initscr)
  (charms:clear)
  (charms:curs-set 0)
  (loop with start = (get-universal-time)
        do (multiple-value-bind (s m h) (get-decoded-time)
             (charms:mvaddstr 0 0 (format nil "~2,'0d:~2,'0d:~2,'0d" h m s)))
           (charms:refresh)
        until (>= (- (get-universal-time) start) 10))
  (charms:endwin))
```

Two problems I've experienced with this:

- This worked only in a terminal, not in the Emacs slime-repl buffer.
- cl-charms couldn't find my installation of the curses library by itself. It was looking for a library named "libcurses.so" or "libncurses.so", but on my system, the library was only present with versioned names. So I had to use the `USE-VALUE` restart during loading the library and provide the alternative value `("libncurses.so.5")` for the list of library names. For using the library often, you should probably want to change the library source code and maybe suggest a patch to the developers.

The cl-charms homepage linked from CLiki is not available, but the repository at http://gitorious.org/cl-charms is.

Here's a short explanation of the ncurses/cl-charms functions I used in the example:

- `initscr` initializes ncurses.
- `clear` clears the screen.
- `curs-set` sets cursor visibility, 0 means invisible.
- `mvaddstr` moves the cursor to the coordinates y, x and writes a string there, replacing what was there on the screen previously.
- `refresh` makes the changes to the screen actually visible.
- `endwin` is the clean-up function to call when you're finished with ncurses.

---

<strike>If I understand correctly what you're trying to do, the best approach seems to be to create a new output stream class (i.e. a subclass of `fundamental-character-output-stream`, assuming your implementation supports Gray Streams). You should probably provide methods specialised for your class at least for `stream-write-char`and `stream-write-string`.</strike>

Then you could wrap code with a redefinition of `*standard-output*` to an instance of your class, somewhat like this:

```
(let ((*standard-output* (make-instance 'your-stream-class
                                        :target *standard-output*)))
  (function-to-be-called-with-wrapped-standard-output))
```

Comment: i'm quite unfamiliar with lisp classes, having never used CLOS and focusing only on a functional approach. is there any resource i can look up to get clarification on your approach?

Comment: If you were more specific in describing what you want to do, I might have some idea about how to do it without CLOS. But if you want to try this approach, you should definitely learn about CLOS, for example with chapters 16 and 17 of Practical Common Lisp (http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/). After that, you can consult your implementation's documentation about Gray Streams.

Comment: so i'm trying to get the chronometer to display something like this: 0:hours 0:minutes 11:seconds . then go on to display 0:hours 0:minutes 12:seconds, and so on.. but on the same space of the previous display, not on another line, or side by side, etc. i did this in python when i wrote a Life simulator by calling clear screen in bash after every pass of a loop construct.

Comment: Well, you can do just the same (clear screen in bash) with Lisp. You'll have to run your Lisp-script from bash (just like in python). In SBCL the shell-out to `clear` will look like this: `(sb-ext:run-program "clear" '() :search t :output t)`

Comment: Yes but now I'm just trying to replace the integers that are incrementing, not the whole line. And that would only make it work in bash.. I'm trying to find a more universal solution (if it exists).

Comment: I don't think, that streams can provide a universal solution to this kind of problem. If you would be dealing with files, you could use `file-position` to "seek" to a specific character in the file and re-write it (see: http://groups.google.com/group/comp.lang.lisp/browse_thread/thread/09496eb7e4fad1e0/3aae226178ddbc60). But how would you map a file to your "display" is up to you.

Comment: * would be dealing = were dealing

Comment: @momo: After the discussion in the comments, I edited my answer to match how I understand your problem now. Please check again.

Comment: @Rörd: this error pops up in the REPL and in the terminal. Evaluation aborted on #<SIMPLE-ERROR "~A is not a Lisp string or pointer.

Comment: @momo: I do not get that error. Is that the full error message you get? Which Lisp implementation are you using?

Comment: @Rörd: that's the error message from the REPL. i created a core image and ran it from bash, i pasted the error at http://paste.pocoo.org/show/526746/. i'm using sbcl.

Comment: @momo: The error message says you're trying to pass NIL to the FFI where it expects a string. I don't see how my code could possibly cause this, so please check if you've changed anything. (I'm using SBCL on Linux, too.)

Comment: @Rörd: besides the code for loading quicklisp and loading the cl-charms package, the code is identical (minor changes to the format call). i ran it first as a script, then created a core image when the script failed. http://paste.pocoo.org/show/526821/

Comment: edit: i just noticed i had the output stream of format was t instead of nil, that fixed it. thanks so much for the help!